# Evaluate the following integral: $ \int \frac{x^2\arctan x}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have been given a few integrals to solve by my math teacher in order to prepare for a competition. In particular, I have some issues with the following integral (which I cannot evaluate by using  *Symbolab* either).

> $$ \int \frac{x^2\arctan x}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

Is there some trick to the question which I have been posed? In any case, could you give me some hints about how to proceed?

Comment: You can always check if the antiderivative of a function exists in elementary functions by putting it on Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: have a look at $u = \arctan x$ as a sub?

Comment: Looks pretty doable to me.  Note that $x^2\arctan x=(x^2+1)\arctan x-\arctan x$.

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes i have and it leaves me with $$1/(1+x^2)$$ which later leaves me with an extra **x**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x^2 arctanx }{1+x^2}dx=\\\int \frac{(x^2+1-1) arctanx }{1+x^2}dx=\\ \int (1-\frac{1}{1+x^2})arctan x dx=\\\int arctanx dx - \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}arctanx dx$$ for the first one use integration by part , and for second use  $u=arctanx\\du=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ $$\int arctanx dx =x arctanx -\int x \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\\x arctanx  -\frac{1}{2}ln(1+x^2)\\$$ $$\int\frac{arctan x}{1+x^2}dx=\int u du=\frac{u^2}{2}=\frac{arctan^2 x}{2} $$

Answer (score 6):

Not wanting to answer questions in teh comments
$$
u = \arctan x \implies du = \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx
$$
thus
$$
\int \frac{x^2\arctan x}{1+x^2}dx = \int x^2 udu = \int u\tan^2u du 
$$
thus you can use integration by parts to solve the rest?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use the identity $\sec^2(u)-\tan^2(u)=1$ to ease out the computations of the integral and then integrate $f(u)=\tan(u)$ using IBP again to complete.

Comment: good to see you man.

Comment: Ah @abel always a pleasure. Keeping well I hope.

Comment: i am good. spring break! how did your interviews go?

Comment: I hope your not "drinking and solving" ;). As for interviews not too bad, just waiting for feedback mostly.

Answer (score 1):

You say (in the tags) that it's a definite integral, but you don't provide the integration limits.

If by chance you're integrating from minus infinity to plus infinity (or $-p$ to $+p$ for any value of p), then you can use the fact that arctan is an odd function: that is, $arctan(-x) = - arctan(x)$.

As $x^2$ is an even function, the whole integrand is odd.

Then the integral over negative $x$ cancels out the integral over positive $x$, and you wind up with zero.

Comment: I now notice the "definite-integrals" tag has been removed, so I presume this answer is actually not of any use.